# Does locating Matlab and loaded data on different hard drives slow down the execution?

Tags: matlab, hard-drive

The Matlab program is installed on hard drive C together with Windows, whereas the scripts and data loaded are saved on hard drive D. Could that be a cause to slower loading of data and slower execution of scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until someone provides hard evidence to the contrary I don't think that this is something that you need to be concerned with.  If there is any impact on execution rate of locating data and Matlab on different disks it will be unnoticeably small.

Once the Matlab program is loaded (from drive C in your case) it will sit in memory ready and waiting for your commands.  It's possible that some of the non-core functionality will be read from disk on demand but you are unlikely to notice, and find it very difficult to measure, the  time this takes.  Whether you then read data and programs from C or D is immaterial.

I look forward to the data that proves me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I compared loading a 140 Mb .mat file from an external USB-2 drive and an internal (IDE or S-ATA) drive.

Loading time from the external drive: > 15 minutes
Loading time from the internal drive: a few seconds

However sometimes the loading from the external drive is fast as well.